# Linker cannot find boost::thread references

Tags: c++, yocto, boost-thread

**Background:**

I'm porting an huge project to a new toolchain (from **gcc 4.7.0** to **gcc 8.2.0** and from **boost 1.55** to **boost 1.68**). The whole SDK is generated by Yocto. There are several libraries and applications, all built with `cmake`.

**The problem:**

All the libraries just build and link fine, meanwhile some of the applications that use `boost::thread` does not link properly. Following an example:

The `cmake` generated command:

> cd /home/italia.priv.org/user/workspace-mk5/git/build/apps/ConfigMngr && /opt/cmake-3.13.0-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ConfigMngr.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi   --std=c++11 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard  -fpermissive -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/ConfigMngr.dir/src/AppConfig.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ConfigMngr.dir/src/AppMain.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ConfigMngr.dir/src/AppStates.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ConfigMngr.dir/src/ConfigMngr.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ConfigMngr.dir/src/dbus_server/ConfigMngrServerApi.cpp.o  -o ConfigMngr -Wl,-rpath,/home/italia.priv.org/user/workspace-mk5/git/targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm: /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.so **/opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so** /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_timer-mt.so ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_autocheck.so ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_config.so ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_dbusapi.a ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_hwifc.a ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_log.so ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_utils.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libdbus-cxx.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libsigc-2.0.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libodb.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libodb-sqlite.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libodb-boost.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libdbus-1.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libgtest.a -pthread

As you can see in **bold** `libboost_thread` is passed to the linker (it is a link to the actual lib). The command above outputs:

> /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::this_thread::interruption_point()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::native_handle()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(boost::detail::mono_platform_timepoint const&, bool&)'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::this_thread::interruption_requested()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::detach()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::interrupt()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
>   /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'

Looking at the symbols exported by `libxxx_core` and grepping for one of the undefined reference:

```
nm -DC libxxx_core.so | grep thread::native_handle
U boost::thread::native_handle()
```

**U** => The symbol is undefined.

Then looking for the same symbol in `libboost_thread`:

```
nm -DC libboost_thread.so.1.68.0 | grep native_handle
0000c3b1 T boost::thread::native_handle()
```

**T** => The symbol is in the text (code) section.

So the linker should be able to solve this dependency (and the others).

**What we have tried**

- Reordering the libraries (`libxx_core` before and after `libboost_thread`)
- Checking each symbols that is not resolved
- Tried different enviroments

Among the undefined reference, the last error given by the linker is

> /opt/poky/2.6.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/8.2.0/real-ld: ../../../targetfs/lib_priv/lib_arm/libxxx_core.so: undefined reference to 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'

Probably there is something related to undefined references. I'm working on it too.

**The question**

Any idea about what could cause these errors or a suggestion on how to debug this behavior properly?

Thanks,
Gabriele

Comment: check whether `libboost_thread-mt.so` is a link to `libboost_thread.so`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk checked, and it actually link to `libboost_thread.so` in the same path

Comment: search in sysroot whether there are any other boost-thread* libs

Comment: I would recommend to use "bitbake -e" to have access to all information you need. For example you would like to know which package from boost are installed with `bitbake -e boost` and checking what exactly does the `do_install` function. Anyway I think you solved your specific problem by modifying your build configuration, isn't it?